# Transform a formula into prenex normal form

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

How do I transform the following formula into prenex normal form without using more quantifiers than necessary?

$$\exists x(\forall y\; \operatorname{Friend}(x,y) \;\& \;\lnot (\exists y\; \operatorname{Foe}(y,x)))$$

I have looked at all of the laws around how to go about putting such formulas in prenex normal forms such as the Conjunction and Disjunction rules, however I can't find any that seem to fit.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I think you misunderstood a key aspect of this site. This is more about *helping* you find the right answer then giving you answers to arbitrary problems. For example, if you were to give us what you've tried, where you've looked, what you've read to answer the problem, and describe why you aren't satisfied/doubt what you've come across, I'm sure others would help. Also, choosing a descriptive title that described the content would help. For more, I recommend reading [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9754)

Comment: @mixedmath I have edited my answer to give an idea of what I have done up til now

Comment: Is your formula parenthesized the way you mean it to be? As written, the $\exists x$ only governs the "Friend" subformula; it does *not* bind the $x$ in the "Foe" subformula. Is that last $x$ supposed to be free? The whole thing would make more sense if that $x$ who has no foes [or "is nobody's foe", whichever way it goes] is the same $x$ who's everybody's friend. For it to mean that, you need one more pair of parens -- another '(' after $\exists x$ and another ')' at the very end.

Comment: I am not completely sure, would you mind explaining how it can be done for both? I would also be interested in seeing the difference it makes

Comment: I don't want to explain how it would be done if x is free in Foe(y,x) ! because my guess is it shouldn't be. To get the meaning "somebody x is everybody's friend and nobody's foe", the x in the last clause has to be the same x as in Friend(x,y). As the formula's written, that's not so. FIX: remove the 2nd ')' after Friend and before '&', and add a ')' at the very end.

Comment: @BrianO I have updated the formula as you have said

Comment: I think that's what's intended, good.

Comment: I deleted my answer after I noticed the 'free variable problem'. Since you fixed it, I fixed my answer :) and restored it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, this formula says, "someone ($x$) is everybody's friend and nobody's foe". (Or, "someone is everybody's friend and has no foes", depending on how $Foe(a,b)$ is to read, and assuming *is-a-foe-of* is not symmetric – the question doesn't say. See comments below with @bof.) Note that you can rename the rightmost bound variable from $y$ to for example $z$, which may make it easier to figure out the meaning when you're first learning how to convert between ordinary language and first order formulas.

Converting it to prenex normal form is fairly straightforward. First, make sure that the bound variables are distinct, then move them across connectives. When a quantifier crosses a negation it changes from universal to existential and vice versa, as seen in step (2). Thus:

$$
\begin{align}
\exists x(\forall y Friend(x,y) \;\&\; \lnot (\exists y Foe(y,x))) &\iff \exists x(\forall y \,Friend(x,y) \;\&\; (\forall y \,\lnot Foe(y,x))) \tag{1}\\
&\iff \exists x(\forall y \,Friend(x,y) \;\&\; \forall y \,\lnot Foe(y,x)) \tag{2}\\
&\iff \exists x\forall y \,(Friend(x,y) \;\&\; \lnot Foe(y,x)) \tag{3}\\
\end{align}
$$

What each step does:

1. $\lnot \exists y$ becomes $\forall y \,\lnot$
2. Drop unneeded parentheses around right subformula
3. Coalesce universal quantifiers in conjoined subformulas into one universal quantifier around the entire conjunction: $$(\forall y\, p) \,\&\, (\forall y\, q) \iff \forall y\, (p \,\&\, q)$$

   In fact the following is valid:
   $$(\forall y\, p) \,\&\, (\forall z\, q) \iff \forall y\, (p \,\&\, q[z/y])$$
   where $q[z/y]$ is the result of substituting $y$ for $z$ in $q$.

Comment: Sure, they can be, I didn't mean to imply that they're one-way implications, I meant it morel like "derivation". I changed it, to be less confusing.

Comment: No need for a new variable $z$, you could just write
$$\exists x\forall y(Friend(x,y)\ \&\ \neg Foe(y,x))$$

Comment: That too, it's equivalent, given '&'. It's less intuitive (not obvious that they are the same), but in keeping with the requirements they should be coalesced. Thanks.

Comment: $\forall yP(y)\ \&\  \forall y Q(y)\iff\forall y(P(y)\ \&\  Q(y))$ seems pretty basic and intuitive to me.

Comment: Perhaps not for beginners. And it has a big effect on how you would render the phrase into ordinary language. With two quantifiers, the statement breaks into two self-contained pieces, "x is everybody's friend", "x is nobody's foe", but coalescing the universal quantifers into one $\forall y$ sort of performs a transpose to where you're saying "everyone y is a friend and not a foe (of x)".

Comment: To pick one last nit, from your English rendering "x is everybody's friend and nobody's for"  it seems that Friend(x,y) and Foe(x,y) are assumed to be symmetric relations. It's not clear if Foe(y,x) is supposed to be read "y is x's foe" or "x is y's foe" but I guess it should be one or the other, else why write Foe(y,x) instead of Foe(x,y).

Comment: I know & I agree. I just didn't want to chew up space putting such a fine point on *that* which after all is a side topic. They don't *have* to be symmetric, but it would be convenient – just to assure that the direction that's written can come out in the catchy way I wrote it :) which I assume is probably the intention of the formula's author. I did think about it. Yes, "Foe(a,b)" is probably most naturally "a is a foe of b", so $\neg \exists y Foe(y,x)$ iff "$x$ has no foes". Another plausible rendering, then: somebody is everyone's friend and has no foes.

Comment: Going back to the point you brought up earlier about the correctness of the parenthesis in the original question, I can see in your initial answer that you renamed $\exists y$ to $\forall z$. Why was this necessary?

Comment: @cp101020304 If we were going to keep that a separate variable, instead of reducing it to a single variable $y$ as now, it has to be changed before moving it to the front because there's another $y$ quantifier, and you *don't* want to "capture" the $y$ in the lefthand conjunct. Simple example with "&" and $\exists$, where you can't collapse both quantifiers to one: $\exists y\; y = 0 \,\&\, \exists y\; y = 1 \iff \exists y\, (y = 0 \,\&\, \exists y\, y = 1)$. <cont>

Comment: @cp101020304 <cont> ...  If we didn't rename the 2nd/inner "exists" variable, if we just move the rightmost $\exists y$ to the front, we'll capture $y$ in $y = 0$, which would turn the true statement just given into the falsehood $\exists y\, \exists y \,(y = 0 \,\&\, y = 1)$ -- equivalent to $\exists y\,(y = 0 \,\&\, y = 1)$

Comment: @cp101020304 So "Why was this necessary" -- only *if* you want to retain 3 variables. (But as your question asks for the minimal number of variables, you *don't* want 3 because 2 suffice... so not only unnecessary but undesirable.) Re other comments: all the statements in the chain of equivalences have the same truth conditions; but, especially noticeable when they're "Englished", rhetorically the 1st and the last have different focus/sense/intension. I also wanted to point out that although the 3rd variable is also $y$, it could be anything, it's a different $y$ than in the "Friend" part.